# Removing Do Not Disturb feature in Motorola phone

Tags: motorola, do-not-disturb

I am trying to completely eliminate Do Not Disturb on my Motorola phone. If I'm in a doctor's office, I just turn the volume down.

I've tried all the simple settings on the Settings pages.

Is there any way to remove it?

Comment: Build a custom ROM with your desired modifications to the source code.